# Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException.error in my code

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, locking

I had my code working (at least somewhat) and I must have changed something, because now it won't even launch. There's no shown errors within the code, but when I try to run it this is what appears:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at azsystem3.Add.run(Main.java:57)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

and (Main.java:57) is this line: `sum.s+=a[i];`
How do I fix it?
Here's my relevant code:

```
package azsystem3;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

class Fill implements Runnable{

    int []a;
    static Random b = new Random();
    int start;
    int end;
    public Fill(int[]a,int start,int end){
        this.a=a;
        this.start=start;
        this.end=end;
    }
    public void run(){

        for(int i=this.start;i<this.end;i++){
            a[i]=b.nextInt(100);

        }
    }
}
class value{
    int s;
}


class Add implements Runnable{
    value sum;
    Lock L ;
    int[]a;
    int start;
    int end;

    //public long  sum=0;
    public Add(int[]a,int start, int end,Lock L,value s){

        this.L=L;
        this.start=start;
        this.end=end;
        sum=s;

    }

    public void run(){
        int i;
        for( i=start;i<end;i++)
            L.lock();
            sum.s+=a[i];
            L.unlock();

    }
}
 class main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        value sum=new value();
        Lock Lock=new ReentrantLock();
        int[] array = new int[100000];

        Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println ("Enter number : ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int tmp = 100000 / n;
        Thread[] t = new Thread[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            t[i] = new Thread(new Fill(array, (i) * tmp, (i + 1) * tmp));
            t[i].start();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            try {
                t[i].join();
            } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
            }
        }
        Thread[] t1 = new Thread[n];
        Add[] add = new Add[n];
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            add[i] = new Add(array, (i) * tmp, (i + 1) * tmp,Lock,sum);
            t1[i] = new Thread(add[i]);
            t1[i].start();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            try {
                t1[i].join();
            } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
            }
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("sum : " + sum);
        System.out.println("time : " + (end - start) + "ms");



        }
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Thread-safety does not only requires locking on `run()`-method in your code, but you should also make your private members of class `Add`, especially the `sum` member, **final**. Otherwise a Thread might see a not fully initialized object of type `value` where the `sum`-member is still `null`.

And note: Please try to follow standard Java code conventions for better readability.

Another observation, this code

```
for( i=start;i<end;i++) // missing opening bracket {
    L.lock();
    sum.s+=a[i];
    L.unlock(); // missing closing bracket }
```

is equivalent to:

```
for( i=start;i<end;i++) {
  L.lock();
}

sum.s+=a[i];
L.unlock();
```

I have no trust in any thread-safety here because of improper handling of brackets and therefore locking.

Comment: @Honey Make all members of class `Add` final and don't forget the missing brackets of the for-loop.

Comment: sorry I made a mistake ;-)

Answer (score 1):

While it looks like a thread-safety issue, the reason for the `NullPointerException` is quite simple:

In the constructor for the `Add` class you forgot to assign the `int` array instance variable `a`, i.e. a simple `this.a=a;` is missing.

That’s a reason why you should declare every instance variable as `final` whenever possible. Then the compiler will tell you about every missing value assignment.

---

Of course, you will have to fix the missing braces in the `Add.run()` method as well as otherwise you will get a dead-lock. In your case only the first thread threw a `NullPointerException` while all other threads were waiting forever.

Comment: As [Meno Hochschild’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23347687/2711488) pointed out, you have to insert the missing braces. But to fix the `NullPointerException` you have to insert the `this.a=a;` into the constructor.

Comment: Good catch for `this.a = a;` One main problem is bad readability in presented code so such things can easily overlooked on first glance. With better coding style much less errors!

Comment: Yep. Good coding style should not be underestimated.